# What type of configration is required to call run multirequest in PHP?

Tags: php, curl, bigcommerce, php-curl

I want to run more than 2500+ call on same time. So i have created a batch of 100 (2500/100 = 25 total call).

```
    // REQUEST_BATCH_LIMIT = 100

    $insert_chunks = array_chunk(['array', 'i want', 'to', 'insert'], REQUEST_BATCH_LIMIT);
    $mh = $running = $ch = [];
    
    foreach ($insert_chunks as $chunk_key => $insert_chunk) {
        
        $mh[$chunk_key] = curl_multi_init();
        $ch[$chunk_key] = [];
        foreach ($insert_chunk as $ch_key => $_POST) {
            
            $ch[$chunk_key][$ch_key] = curl_init('[Dynamic path of API]');
            curl_setopt($ch[$chunk_key][$ch_key], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_multi_add_handle($mh[$chunk_key], $ch[$chunk_key][$ch_key]);
        }
        
        do {
            curl_multi_exec($mh[$chunk_key], $running[$chunk_key]);
            curl_multi_select($mh[$chunk_key]);
        } while ($running[$chunk_key] > 0);
        
        foreach(array_keys($ch[$chunk_key]) as $ch_key) {
            $response = curl_getinfo($ch[$chunk_key][$ch_key]);
            $returned_data = curl_multi_getcontent($ch[$chunk_key][$ch_key]);
            curl_multi_remove_handle($mh[$chunk_key], $ch[$chunk_key][$ch_key]);
        }
        curl_multi_close($mh[$chunk_key]);
    }
```

When i running this in local the system is hanged totally.

But this limit of batch like 100, 500 are not same on different device and server, so what is the reason about it? and what changes should i do to increase it?

If i am adding 1000 data with batch of 50, so for every batch 50 records should insert, but it insert randomly for a batch like 40, 42, 48, etc. so way this is skipped calls? (If i am using single record with simple cURL using loop then it is working fine.)

***P.S. This code is i am using for bigcommrece API.***

Comment: If i am adding 1000 data with batch of 50, so for every batch 50 records should insert, but it insert randomly for a batch like 40, 42, 48, etc...

Comment: Please add all such clarification to your question by editing, along with a description of that problem. Does that mean that cURL skips calls to the external API, or that the API refuses to handle some of these calls?

Comment: Okay, if i call it without multi cURL, means only one by one record using loop then all are added.

Comment: Is there a throttling limit on calling the external API?

Comment: This code is i am using for bigcommerce, I don't think it is because every time it stores different data like i am trying to insert 2200 data but it stores 1300, 1767, 1485, etc,...

Answer (score 1):

The BigCommerce API definitely throttles requests. The limits are different depending on which plan you are on.

https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Platform-Limits

The "Standard Plan" is 20,000 per hour. I'm not sure how that is really implemented, though, because in my own experience, I've been throttled before hitting 20,000 requests in an hour.

As Nico Haase suggests, the key is for you to log every response you get from the BigCommerce API. While not a perfect system, they do usually provide a response that is helpful to understand the failure.

I run a process that makes thousands of API requests every day. I do sometimes have requests that fail as if the BigCommerce API simply dropped the connection.